# Changing Mac Folder Icon

Tags: finder

I'm running the latest version of Mavericks and I can't seem to change the folder icons. I've gone to get info and pasted it in whilst being clicked on the folder image but nothing happens.

I've only had this iMac a few weeks. To set it up I used migration assistance, ever since doing that I've been unable to change the folder image. Everything I've tried so far has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is get the image that you are wanting to change the icon of your image. right click on the folder icon, and click "Get Info," it will load the information, and at the top, it will show the folder icon as it does here.

[image]

What you do is drag the new icon to where the folder icon next to School is. It will appear with a + icon next to your image, and let go. It will then change the icon of your folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. Both require you to open the info window on a folder (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or File>Get Info...)
Usually dragging an icon onto the folder icon in the info window works. 
There *are* times where this doesn't work and I haven't figured out exactly why. Sometimes dragging the image doesn't work either, so if one doesn't work, try the other.
To workaround this, open the image in Preview, select all and copy (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), click on the icon in the info window (which will highlight the folder icon) and paste (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Comment: I didn't know the second way you describe. Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried all of the above but nothing has worked, could it be that I have to move a .plist folder to the trash? I've been on the phone to Apple before and they told me to do that for another issue, but could that fix it? If so, do you know which one I'd have to delete?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no `.plist` file for that. The information is stored directly in the file's metadata. You may be able to use an OpenMeta editor to edit it, but a cursory search didn't turn up anything useful. OpenMeta is an open standard, so theoretically it could work.

Comment: There is `mdls` and `xattr`, which gets and sets file attributes respectively. However, when I did `mdls` on a file that had a custom icon, the attribute `kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon` returned null. How comfortable are you with Terminal commands?